# trigger.io - Can't create ipa-file anymore

Tags: forge

I usually use trigger.io to generate my ipa-Files for iOS. Now when I want to generate the file, I get the following error message:

Failed when running /usr/bin/codesign: codesign_allocate: object: /Users/mherceg/Desktop/ag-app/development/ios/device-ios.app/Forge malformed object (unknown load command 39)
/Users/mherceg/Desktop/ag-app/development/ios/device-ios.app: object file format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable

It worked yesterday, but now it doesn't. Any help is very welcome.

Thanks,

enne

Comment: Yeah, I received this error message 6 AM eastern time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is *probably* to do with [v1.4.16](http://docs.trigger.io/en/latest/release-notes.html#v1-4-16) of our platform, where we switched over to building on Xcode 4.5: I'd recommend upgrading Xcode and make sure the Command-line Tools (Preferences ↦ Downloads) are installed.

Comment: Also verified that this was the problem. I downgraded to 1.4.15, and it compiled on the mobile device correctly.