# Packaging for iOS mysteriously fails

Tags: ios, trigger.io, forge

I ran this command to create an .ipa file with forge, and it worked:

```
forge package ios --ios.profile.provisioning_profile name.mobileprovision
```

Where "name" is the name of my provisioning profile.

The program crashed immediately on my iPhone. I tried repackaging using the exact same bash command, but now I get this error:

```
[  ERROR] Failed when running /usr/bin/codesign: codesign_allocate: object: /Users/me/Coding/gits/Project/development/ios/device-ios.app/Forge malformed object (unknown load command 43)
/Users/me/Coding/gits/Project/development/ios/device-ios.app: object file format unrecognized, invalid, or unsuitable
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12679229/542425

Comment: I downgraded to 1.4 and it didn't work. 

Then I completely reinstalled Xcode and it did. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the future - I tried following the advice of [trigger.io - Can't create ipa-file anymore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12679229/trigger-io-cant-create-ipa-file-anymore) to downgrade to a lower version of forge. That didn't work.

But completely reinstalling XCode did! So if you run into this problem, as a last resort you could always try that!